# UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate> vs UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the different between the following class declarations..

```
@interface RotatableViewController : UISplitViewController

@interface RotatableViewController : UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
```

A very basic question, but I am learning iOS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@interface RotatableViewController : UISplitViewController
```

Here, your RotatableViewController extends UISplitViewController. That means your RotatableViewController can do [what an UISplitViewController can do](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Since UISplitViewController is a subclass of UIViewController, your class automatically inherits from UIViewController too. So it can also do what a UIViewController can do.

```
@interface RotatableViewController : UIViewController
```

This way, your class inherits from UIViewController class.

```
@interface RotatableViewController : UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
```

This means your class is a subclass is a subclass of UIViewController and it also implements the functions defined in [UISplitViewControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

I strongly suggest reading about [Delegation Pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) in Objective-C to learn what you would need this for.

Comment: I corrected my question, the brackets got removed from the original question

Comment: I think I understand.  I was confused by the syntax as it's a bit different than C#.  It's fair to say anything in the <> brackets is that we are implementing an interface (interface as defined by C#, a proxy as it would be defined in Objective-C) ?

Comment: Yes. Protocol in Objective-C = interface in C#/Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface RotatableViewController : UISplitViewController
```

The above statement indicates that the `RotatableViewController` is a subclass of `UISplitViewController` while in

```
@interface RotatableViewController :UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
```

the above statement indicates that the RotatableViewController is a
subclass of `UIViewController` and you are conforming the delegate method of `UISplitViewController` in `currentViewController(RotatableViewController)`

Comment: I corrected my question, the brackets got removed from the original question

Answer (score 0):

One inherits from UISplitViewController the other from UIViewController.

In addition to that (acording to your updates response) the controllerDelegate between < ...> states that your class conforms to this class' delegate

Comment: Yeah I know that.  I corrected my question, the brackets got removed from the original question.

Comment: The delegate is what is listed between < ... >. The first definition just inherits, the second says that you are using the class's delegate methods. You aren't adding capabilities, just implementing the methods you need to use it

Comment: Ok, so if I am inheriting UISplitViewController, it is a delegate then naturally by default, or do I still need to specify it as a delegate.  Example @interface RotatableViewController :UISplitViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate> ?

Comment: If you inherit, you get the functionality from the superclass. Then if you want to make your custom class a delegate after adding more finctionality, etc... then you can use your new subclass as a delegate (but you have to declare it). You should read up on delegate to see what the purpose is (in summary it is a way to have your delegate class notified of changes by another class)

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class named `RotatableViewController` that inherits from `UISplitViewController`:

```
@interface RotatableViewController : UISplitViewController
```

Declare a class named `RotatableViewController` that inherits from `UIViewController` and promises to implement to the required methods inside of `UISplitViewControllerDelegate`:

```
@interface RotatableViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
```